# set zone when Creating Azure Managed Disk via C# SDK

Tags: c#, azure

I'm following the sample [C# Managed Disk Azure SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/compute/Azure.ResourceManager.Compute/samples/Sample1_ManagingDisks.md) where the code looks like this:

```
ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
SubscriptionResource subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
ResourceGroupCollection rgCollection = subscription.GetResourceGroups();
// With the collection, we can create a new resource group with an specific name
string rgName = "myRgName";
AzureLocation location = AzureLocation.WestUS2;
ArmOperation<ResourceGroupResource> lro = await rgCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, rgName, new ResourceGroupData(location));
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = lro.Value;
```

This creates the disk, however the VMs that I want to attach this to is in zone 1 (East US zone 1). The disks are in just East US. How do I set the zone when creating the disk, or change the zone via the SDK?

the zones property is a read only list.
the location doesn't allow you to specify the zone.
I've tried both premium LRS and premium ZRS SKUs

I've tested this against a disk I created by hand in the portal and the zone is the only difference between the two and the one I provision by hand attaches and functions as expected.